# Ruby class refresh/rollback deleted array elements

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to create a ruby class for a game called times up. Essentially, i want the following functionality to start with:

- each instance of the class is a game.
- Each game has an array of words which are input by the players.
- the class should enable getting a random element out of the array of words and subsequently removing that elemennt from play.
- When all the words are out of the "hat", the game should be able to refresh the array to its original content, simulating putting the words back into the hat for the next round.

It is this last point that I am having trouble with.. I tried to create a dummy array or a base array that is not modified and then just set the emptied array to the base array at the end of a round but this only results in me removing elements from the base array in the second round and being left with two empty arrays at the end of the second round :( how do i create a copy which will not be modified??

Here is my code:

```
class TimesUp

  def initialize
    @hat = []
    @basehat = []
  end

  def NewWord(word)
    @hat.push(word)
    @basehat.push(word)
  end

  def grab
    if @hat.empty?
        puts "End of round!"
    else
        l = @hat.length
        word = rand(l)
        puts @hat[word]
        @hat.delete_at(word)
    end
  end

  def printout
    puts @hat
  end

  # here is where i try to set the game array to the 'base' array. 
  def refresh
    @hat = @basehat
    @basehat = @basehat
  end
end
```

Comment: You're explicitly setting two references to the same object. You probably need to dupe, or just recreate it from the list of words.

Comment: Try something like `loop do; @hat = basehat.dup; <play the game>; <break when tired of playing>; end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Object#dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-dup), and `clone` might also be an option.

```
def refresh
  @hat = @basehat.dup
  @basehat = @basehat.dup
end
```

Comment: Great this seems to have worked thanks! I still don't understand why my method doesn't work though, I thought that when I set my "hat" to "basehat", my "hat" variable would simply take the values associated with the "basehat" array. However, playing the game further reveals that elements are being removed from "basehat" as well. Why is this? Is setting it equal not the same as copying I guess?

Comment: you just assigned the basehat to hat, both were the same this removing from hat equals removign from basehat. dup/clone create new arrays and actually copy the contents over. caveat: if you have complex objects in your basehat and change their state in hat (say call some method on them) their state will also change in the basehat. you'd have to write a deep clone method in that case.